# Why does the php file not open when i click button second time?

Tags: javascript, php

```
const baseUrl = "components/data.php";

function loadData(requestType, containerSelector, limitVal, offsetVal) {
  const container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      container.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhr.open(
    "POST",
    `${baseUrl}?requestType=${requestType}&limit=${limitVal}&offset=${offsetVal}`,
    true
  );
  xhr.send();
}

const eventsBtn = document.getElementById("events");
eventsBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("Loading events");
  loadData("getEvents", ".events-container", 5, 0);
});

const feedBtn = document.querySelector("#feed");
feedBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("Loading posts");
  loadData("getPosts", ".feed", 5, 0);
});
```

here is the code which is calling content from php file using js

When i try to call the function 2nd time using any button, the file path is changing and i am getting 404 error, on first click the function always read right content but on 2nd time the url is wrong

for example its changing from components/data.php to /components/data.php

Comment: A note on your JS: you seem to be mixing _ancient_ JS with normal modern JS: switch that `loadData` function to use `fetch`, not the legacy `XMLHttpRequest`, and rewrite it to not use the even more legacy `var`. Especially when at the same time, you _are_ using modern templating strings. Just go with modern JS for everything =) That said, if "when i try to call the function 2nd time using any button, the file path is changing and i am getting 404 error", you should show proof of that in your post: say which button you press, and then which URL you see it call in dev tools, for each press.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i have changed it to use axios but what i meant by the error is when i am clicking any button 2nd time which uses this function it shows error 404, the file path is changing for example from "components/data.php"; to "/components/data.php";

Comment: Those are [details relevant to the problem](/help/how-to-ask), so put that in your post, not in a comment. Update your post's code to reflect the code you're _actually_ using. If you switched to Axios, show _that_ code. Also, nothing in the code you're showing will change the URL that you're posting to, as your `baseUrl` is a const, so it _can't_ be changed without throwing an error. The only way the request might go from relative to absolute is if you have a `<base>` element, so: run through the [mcve] exercise to find out where and why things go wrong.